# Having trouble getting a touch location in sprite-kit screne

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making a game for a final project and I need to know where the user touches so I can move the player around.

here is the .h file

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface BYFGameScene : SKScene
@end
```

the header of the .m

```
#import "BYFGameScene.h"

@interface BYFGameScene()

@property BOOL contentCreated;
@property (nonatomic)SKSpriteNode *player;

@end

@implementation BYFGameScene



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint *location = [[touches anyObject] location];

    NSLog(@"the location is %@",location);

}
```

I think that touches began would be the appropriate method to get the location and in previous apps this is how I would get the location but it keeps throwing a exception and I am not sure why.

I have also tried

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGFloat location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    NSLog(@"the location is %f",location);

}
```

but it gives an error saying that UIView and BYFGameScene(the current scene) are not compatible types

also how would I manipulate the players position? 
\here is what I thought would work but it does not.

```
-(void)moveUp
{
    if(self.player.position==CGpoint 700)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        self.player.position = self.player.position +100;
    }
}
```

700 would be the max position

Any help would be appreciated
thanks

Comment: Add the full stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Could `nodeAtPoint` be what you're looking for? In what class do you implements theses methods?

Comment: What is the full stacktrace? and I do not think nodeAtPoint would be right because the scene is full of nodes i want the location in the scene to compare with the player so if you click above him he will move one space up and vice versa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    //touch point, see locationInNode
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

 //   SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
```

Comment: who gave a negative vote without explaining why? also negative vote to the correct answer

Comment: Probably got a negative vote for referencing self without saying where the code is, so self is unknown. But I'm only guessing. I wouldn't give a negative "vote" for that, I'd just ask the question... where is this code, ergo, what/who is self?